# How to join ManyToMany querysets in Django/Python

Tags: python, django

For example, I have 2 models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   achievement = models.ManyToManyField('Achievement')

class Achievement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I need get all achievements of several users, i think, it should be something like this:

```
for user in User.objects.filter(bla-bla):
  achievement_list += user.achievement
```

But it returns error "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable"

Comment: `[u.achievement_set.values_list('name', flat=True) for u in User.objects.filter(bla-bla)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user.achievement` is a `ManyRelatedManager`, similar to how, say, `Achievement.objects` is a `Manager`.  Try instead `user.achievement.all()` or `user.achievement.filter(...)` (with whatever filter you may want).